# Find out Discount per Line Item in Shopware 6

Tags: shopware6

Is there a way to find out a discount per line item in orders?

As I understand (after looking at the table `order_line_item`), the full discount is added as a own line item.

I believe we would have to hook into the discount calculation and log the discount per order item - and of course there might be discounts which cannot be easily accounted to one position.

EDIT / Some warning: composition is empty for this rule, even "only for selected products" is on:

[image: Screenshot Discount]

If we configure a rule by set, the composition field is there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The discount position in the table `order_line_item` should have the discount for each line item in the column `payload`. Something like this:

[image]

I would recommend not changing the logic in the shop and rather use the information from the payload for synchronisation with 3rd party systems like ERP.

Comment: Bonus question: So the `composition.id` field seems referencing to the identifier column in the same order? This identifier does not seem to be unique. Is it the product ID? We seem to have the same identifier multiple times on an order (we sell courses and have a custom field for the participant name, maybe that's why)

Comment: There is no core function to analyse that payload, right? It is to be parsed manually?

Comment: @Alex In my test the composition.id referenced always to the column `identifier` in the order_line_item table.

Comment: I edited my question, composition is empty for some discounts, I believe because we do not use "set groups" ? Basically it's a warning; I believe that is not easily solvable for that cases.

Comment: I think this is because in your screenshot the promotion is set to "absolute", so there is no discount that is calculated based on the line items. Absolute positions have no relation to the different line items.